# unable to change button color on click using javascript in materialize.css

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I am new to materialize.css and i actually i want to change the button color on click using javascript. Each button on click has to yield a different color depending on the button content.  But when i click on he button it doesnt change it color.

```
  <div class=" buttons  row center-align">
<button class="btn col s12 m6 deep-purple darken-4 center-align" id='button0'  onclick ="answer('0')" style ="display:none"><span class=" flow-text white-text text-darken-2" id="option0"></span></button><br>  
<button class="btn col s12 m6 deep-purple darken-4 center-align" id='button1'  onclick ="answer('1')" style ="display:none"><span class=" flow-text white-text text-darken-2" id="option1"></span></button><br>
<button class="btn col s12 m6 deep-purple darken-4 center-align" id='button2'  onclick ="answer('2')" style ="display:none"><span class=" flow-text white-text text-darken-2" id="option2"></span></button><br>
<button class="btn col s12 m6 deep-purple darken-4 center-align" id='button3'  onclick ="answer('3')" style ="display:none"><span class=" flow-text white-text text-darken-2" id="option3"></span></button><br>
 </div>
```

javascript

```
 function answer(ans){
  var z = document.getElementById('option'+ans);
  var choice = z.innerHTML;
  var b = document.getElementById('button'+ans);
     if(choice == questions[x].answer){
       b.style.backgroundColor = '#008000'; 
       b.style.color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';}
     else{
       b.style.backgroundColor = '#700000';
       b.style.color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';}
```

Comment: can you add the <option> codes as well?  can't tell what z.innerHTML is.

Comment: option is the id of the span inside the button; which means he text inside the button. Btw the logic is working fine i have certain other statements which execute in the if-else statements, its only that the button color are not changing

Comment: you missing a '}' at the bottom?  was that a copy error?

Comment: yeah. .copy error. .is it that for this style change on materialize.css we need jquery?

Comment: actually i figured it out, i had to remove the button color button from the class and customise the background color of the button in custom css file created by me.

Comment: can you create an answer for what you found, and then approve it?  gives others the benefit of your lessons learned.

Comment: yeah sure!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

html

```
<div class=" buttons  row center-align">
<button class="button col s12 m6  center-align" id='button0'  onclick ="answer('0')" style ="display:none"><span class=" flow-text white-text text-darken-2" id="option0"></span></button><br>  
<button class="button col s12 m6  center-align" id='button1'  onclick ="answer('1')" style ="display:none"><span class=" flow-text white-text text-darken-2" id="option1"></span></button><br>
<button class="button col s12 m6  center-align" id='button2'  onclick ="answer('2')" style ="display:none"><span class=" flow-text white-text text-darken-2" id="option2"></span></button><br>
<button class="button col s12 m6  center-align" id='button3'  onclick ="answer('3')" style ="display:none"><span class=" flow-text white-text text-darken-2" id="option3"></span></button><br>
```

Just remove the materializecss button class 'btn' and replace with any name , i did with button and remove the  materializecss color class inside the buttons tag, so finally each buttons will be of class:

```
 'button col s12 m6  center-align'
```

and in self-created css file for this html file;(main.css)

```
.button.col.s12.m6.center-align{
   background-color: #311b92;
padding: 10px 20px 10px;
border-radius: 50px;
font-size: 2em;}
```

and now when we apply the above javascript method mentioned in the question; the button color will change on click